# CSS style scope with rules within an ID

Tags: html, css, scope

If I have a table with ID `tableProducts` and it's style is defined in products.css like this:

```
#tableProducts {
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

How do I format the CSS rule so that any `td`, `tr`, or `p` within tableProducts will inherit the CSS rules so that any other table with a different ID will not inherit the rules defined like so:

```
#tableProducts tr, td {
      text-align:center;
}
```

The text-align works properly however other tables on the page are applying the `tr, td` rules defined above.

I am aware that I could simply define a class for the elements `<tr>` and `<td>` to use, but I am trying to better my understanding of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason other tables inherit the styles is because the second selector after the comma targets all the `<td>` elements in the page, in other words you should limit the scope of your selector by prefixing it with `#tableProducts`, like so:

```
#tableProducts tr, #tableProducts td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**NOTE:** it's a good practice to put each selector in a new line, this helps you a lot with clarity and makes your code much more readable, it's also a bad practice to use IDs in your CSS, use classes instead, also when trying to name your classes make sure they contain only lowercase letters, numbers and hyphens, so the best answer to your question would be:

```
.table-products tr,
.table-products td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope it helped : )

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace ...

```
#tableProducts tr, td {
      text-align:center;
}
```

... with ...

```
#tableProducts tr, #tableProducts td {
      text-align:center;
}
```

---

#### Explanation

Selector `#tableProducts tr, td` applies to all elements that match one of these two selectors :

- `#tableProducts tr`
- `td`

This means that selector `#tableProducts tr, td` will apply to ALL `td` elements.

Selector `#tableProducts tr, #tableProducts td` applies to all elements that match one of these two selectors :

- `#tableProducts tr`
- `#tableProducts td`

Replacing `#tableProducts tr, td` with `#tableProducts tr, #tableProducts td` therefore means that your selector no longer applies to all `td` elements, but only to `td` elements inside `#tableProducts`, which is what you're going for!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0qvm6tc6/

```
#tableProducts > tr, td {
          text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: OP wants `td` within other tables ***not*** centered: _"any other table with a different ID will not inherit the rules"_. This doesn't fix that, and using direct child (`>`) breaks `#tableProducts` selector if it has `<thead> / <tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
#tableProducts tr,#tableProducts td{
      text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#tableProducts tbody tr td{
   text-align:center;
}
```